# Illustrator won't remember layer collapse state

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

Running Illustrator CS5 on Mac OS 10.7

Reopening an Illustrator document expands all layers

For files containing a large amount of layers, this is very irritating.

Is this a general problem or just my version/me?

Comment: This has been a constant headache for me also. This has been brought up on Adobe's forums a couple times, I hope someone in the forum finds a work around: 1. http://forums.adobe.com/message/4302319#4302319 2. http://forums.adobe.com/message/4302319#4302319 I hope they fix this soon. My blood boils a little when I know I have to open a file with hundreds of layers.

Comment: It's still a consistent issue for us now that we've moved to Mavericks 9.1/CS6. In fact it's worsened. I collapse the layers, but the minute I select something on a layer that has sublayers, the arrow turns down again.

Answer (score 3):

It's a consistent issue.

And there is **nothing** you can do about it. Users have been asking for a fix since..... well.. at least version 10, if not longer.

The simplest workaround is to place all your layers into a new top layer. Then, upon opening a file, you can Option/Alt click that top layer to collapse all internal sub-layers. This workaround has it's benefits and detriments. So it's not perfect.

I just wish they'd get around to fixing it.

Comment: yes my bad - i just found this http://forums.adobe.com/message/4302840 file as firstworldproblems :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with nested layers. If you build clean AI files, you use these a lot. The lack of a preference for this really stinks, but if you're organized with your top level layers it's not too bad.